# Configure ext_job_cache on salt master

Tags: elasticsearch, salt-stack

I am trying to set `ext_job_cache` to `elasticsearch` on my master config file but I'm getting this error when trying to ping a minion.

```
'TypeError: elasticsearch.save_load is not a callable'
```

I have installed the `elasticsearch.py` module. The minions have the settings for `elasticsearch` returner in their configs(host, shards, replicas).

The same version is installed on all minions and master. I really don't know what the problem is. `master_job_cache` option is working well and sending data to ES.
I've read that some functions, like `get_jids`, are needed for `ext_job_cache` but I didn't understand exactly what I'm supossed to do. 
The error is in concern with `save_load` which exists in `elasticsearch.py`

Comment: Probably it is a version issue. What is your version?

Comment: Salt master : 2016.3.2
Elasticsearch server : 2.3.5
elasticsearch.py : 2.3.0